# Cant find project file after running gyp

Tags: chromium, chromium-embedded, gyp

I am trying to build chromium embedded to test pepper API as they do [here](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=10509)

1. Build CEF3/Chromium from source code as described at https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembed ... ndBuilding.
2. Edit C:\chromium\src\build\some.gyp, add '../ppapi/ppapi_internal.gyp:ppapi_example_paint_manager' in the 'dependencies' section.
3. Run `gclient runhooks` from the chromium src directory to update the build files.
4. Open C:\chromium\src\build\some.sln (on equivalent on other platforms) and build the ppapi_example_paint_manager target to create ppapi_example_paint_manager.dll.

However i dont seem to get any project file "some.*" after the build, looking in the source folder (I am on a mac), I would expect an *.xcproj file or similar in my '..chromium/src/build' folder.

Am I missing some step?

Here is the output:

```
gclient runhooks

________ running '/usr/bin/python src/build/download_nacl_toolchains.py --no-arm-trusted --keep' in '/Users/daka/wimp/chromium'
/Users/daka/wimp/chromium/src/native_client/toolchain/.tars/toolchain_mac_x86.tar.bz2 is already up to date.
/Users/daka/wimp/chromium/src/native_client/toolchain/.tars/toolchain_mac_x86.tar.bz2 is already up to date.
mac_x86: already up to date.
/Users/daka/wimp/chromium/src/native_client/toolchain/.tars/naclsdk_mac_x86.tgz is already up to date.
/Users/daka/wimp/chromium/src/native_client/toolchain/.tars/naclsdk_mac_x86.tgz is already up to date.
mac_x86_newlib: already up to date.
/Users/daka/wimp/chromium/src/native_client/toolchain/.tars/naclsdk_pnacl_mac_x86.tgz is already up to date.
/Users/daka/wimp/chromium/src/native_client/toolchain/.tars/naclsdk_pnacl_mac_x86.tgz is already up to date.
pnacl_mac_x86: already up to date.
/Users/daka/wimp/chromium/src/native_client/toolchain/.tars/naclsdk_pnacl_translator.tgz is already up to date.
/Users/daka/wimp/chromium/src/native_client/toolchain/.tars/naclsdk_pnacl_translator.tgz is already up to date.
pnacl_translator: already up to date.

________ running '/usr/bin/python src/build/linux/install-arm-sysroot.py --linux-only' in '/Users/daka/wimp/chromium'

________ running '/usr/bin/python src/chrome/installer/linux/sysroot_scripts/install-debian.wheezy.sysroot.py --linux-only --arch=amd64' in '/Users/daka/wimp/chromium'

________ running '/usr/bin/python src/chrome/installer/linux/sysroot_scripts/install-debian.wheezy.sysroot.py --linux-only --arch=i386' in '/Users/daka/wimp/chromium'

________ running '/usr/bin/python src/tools/clang/scripts/update.py --if-needed' in '/Users/daka/wimp/chromium'
Clang already at 202555-4

________ running '/usr/bin/python src/build/util/lastchange.py -o src/build/util/LASTCHANGE' in '/Users/daka/wimp/chromium'

________ running '/usr/bin/python src/build/util/lastchange.py -s src/third_party/WebKit -o src/build/util/LASTCHANGE.blink' in '/Users/daka/wimp/chromium'

________ running 'download_from_google_storage --no_resume --platform=win32 --no_auth --bucket chromium-gn -s src/tools/gn/bin/win/gn.exe.sha1' in '/Users/daka/wimp/chromium'

________ running 'download_from_google_storage --no_resume --platform=darwin --no_auth --bucket chromium-gn -s src/tools/gn/bin/mac/gn.sha1' in '/Users/daka/wimp/chromium'

________ running 'download_from_google_storage --no_resume --platform=linux* --no_auth --bucket chromium-gn -s src/tools/gn/bin/linux/gn.sha1' in '/Users/daka/wimp/chromium'

________ running 'download_from_google_storage --no_resume --platform=linux* --no_auth --bucket chromium-gn -s src/tools/gn/bin/linux/gn32.sha1' in '/Users/daka/wimp/chromium'

________ running 'download_from_google_storage --no_resume --platform=win32 --no_auth --bucket chromium-clang-format -s src/third_party/clang_format/bin/win/clang-format.exe.sha1' in '/Users/daka/wimp/chromium'

________ running 'download_from_google_storage --no_resume --platform=darwin --no_auth --bucket chromium-clang-format -s src/third_party/clang_format/bin/mac/clang-format.sha1' in '/Users/daka/wimp/chromium'

________ running 'download_from_google_storage --no_resume --platform=linux* --no_auth --bucket chromium-clang-format -s src/third_party/clang_format/bin/linux/clang-format.sha1' in '/Users/daka/wimp/chromium'

________ running 'download_from_google_storage --no_resume --platform=linux* --no_auth --bucket chromium-eu-strip -s src/build/linux/bin/eu-strip.sha1' in '/Users/daka/wimp/chromium'

________ running '/usr/bin/python src/build/gyp_chromium' in '/Users/daka/wimp/chromium'
Updating projects from gyp files...
Running build/landmines.py...
Hook '/usr/bin/python src/build/gyp_chromium' took 54.69 secs
```

Here is my gyp file:

```
# Copyright (c) 2011 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
# Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
# found in the LICENSE file.
{
  'targets': [
    {
      'target_name': 'some',
      'type': 'none',
      'dependencies': [
        # This file is intended to be locally modified. List the targets you use
        # regularly. The generated some.sln will contains projects for only
        # those targets and the targets they are transitively dependent on. This
        # can result in a solution that loads and unloads faster in Visual
        # Studio.
        #
        # Tip: Create a dummy CL to hold your local edits to this file, so they
        # don't accidentally get added to another CL that you are editing.
        #
        # Example:
        # '../chrome/chrome.gyp:chrome',
        '../ppapi/ppapi_internal.gyp:ppapi_example_paint_manager'
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears i had specified ninja as toolchain in an earlier stage, this can be changed to xcode:

```
export GYP_GENERATORS='ninja'
```

Change to:

```
export GYP_GENERATORS='xcode'
```